# mysql - Unknown column in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Tags: php, mysql

I have following table named 'votes', where participant's upvote(1) and downvote(-1) stores. I want to get top 3 voted participant ids and its total votes, where total vote = upvote - downvote. I wrote query as given below but getting error : "Unknown column 'total_votes' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'"

```
table 'votes'
---------------------------------
| participant_id | vote| voter_id
+------+-------+---------+------+
|              1 | 1   |  1
|              2 | 1   |  1
|              3 | 1   |  1
|              4 | -1  |  1
|              5 | 1   |  1

|              1 | -1  |  2
|              2 | 1   |  2
|              3 | 1   |  2
|              4 | 1   |  2
|              5 | 1   |  2

|              1 | 1   |  3
|              2 | 1   |  3
|              3 | -1  |  3
|              4 | -1  |  3
+------+-------+---------+-----+
```

```
SELECT `participant_id`, SUM( `vote` ) AS total_votes FROM `votes` 
WHERE total_votes IN  
(SELECT total_votes FROM  
(SELECT DISTINCT (SUM( vote )) AS total_votes FROM  `votes` GROUP BY  `participant_id` 
ORDER BY `total_votes` DESC LIMIT 0 , 3) AS temp )  
GROUP BY `participant_id`
```

```
Expected result would be
-------------------------------
| participant_id | total_votes
+------+-------+--------+------+
|              2 | 3   
|              5 | 2   
|              1 | 1   
|              3 | 1   
+------+-------+--------+------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite your query by using join to get the top participants whose vote score lies in top 3 votes i.e top 3 votes are (3,2,1)

```
SELECT t.* FROM
(SELECT `participant_id`, SUM( `vote` ) AS total_votes 
FROM `votes` 
GROUP BY `participant_id`
) t
JOIN  (SELECT SUM( `vote` ) AS total_votes FROM `votes` 
GROUP BY `participant_id`
ORDER BY `total_votes` DESC LIMIT 0 , 3 ) t1
USING(total_votes)
ORDER BY t.total_votes DESC
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5e51f/3)

Comment: this is working great... only I have to add is distinct for participant_ids... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is following, as there is no `total_votes` column in your table:

```
SELECT `participant_id`, SUM( `vote` ) AS total_votes FROM `votes` 
WHERE votes IN  
(SELECT total_votes FROM  
(SELECT DISTINCT (SUM( vote )) AS total_votes FROM  `votes` GROUP BY  `participant_id` 
ORDER BY `total_votes` DESC LIMIT 0 , 3) AS temp )  
GROUP BY `participant_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple query:

```
SELECT 
participant_id, total_votes 
FROM 
(SELECT participant_id,SUM(vote) total_votes 
FROM votes 
GROUP BY participant_id) a 
ORDER BY total_votes DESC 
LIMIT 3;
```

To get all participants for top 3 voting you can use below query:

```
SELECT 
a.participant_id, b.total_votes 
FROM 
(SELECT participant_id, SUM(vote) total_votes 
FROM votes 
GROUP BY participant_id) a 
JOIN 
(SELECT participant_id,SUM(vote) total_votes 
FROM votes 
GROUP BY participant_id 
ORDER BY total_votes DESC LIMIT 3) b
ON a.total_votes=b.total_votes 
ORDER BY total_votes DESC;
```

Comment: @hardik this query will skip the participants if they had same score as in your sample data the participant with id 3 is skipped,although this participant has also the vote score of top 3s

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid as per query he need only top 3.

Comment: @ZafarMalik see his question and *Expected result*  part

Comment: right @khalid... your answer is perfect... I dont want only top 3 participant_ids but top 3 vote gators, that may have same votes...

Comment: ok @hardik 2nd query will fulfill your requirement, I was misunderstood your requirement earlier. thanks khalid for your feedback.

Comment: @ZafarMalik what is the difference in your second query logically it looks same as mine ?